# Write to a very large number of Excel cells at once

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code

```
Dim Destination As Range
Set Destination = Cells(2, 1)
Set Destination = Destination.Resize(UBound(X_values), 1)
Destination.Value = Application.Transpose(X_values)
```

With which i want to insert the values in `X_values` into column 1, starting at row 2. The above code works fine for most data set, but i typically also want to use it on data with more than 100000 points, upon which i get the error "Type mismatch"

The values in `X_values`, are time data of the form `0`, `1e-5`, `2e-5`, and so on.

Can anyone suggest a simple way around this? why is it happening?

Edit: from what i can see, the range at destination is the correct size (it has the same number of rows as X_values)
Also, i am not writing to each cell individually for obvious reasons: the updates take forever

Comment: While this is a little old, I am wondering if it points to the same problem: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/177991  -Too many array elements

Comment: You'll need to create a second array (1 to ubound(X_values, 1 to 1) and copy your data to it in a loop.  You can then drop that second array directly to the sheet.

Comment: Or create X_values as a 2D array from the start

Comment: @AlanWaage It could well be the problem. The numbers however, dont work: My maximum number of rows is over 1 million, so that is not the issue, and while it says the maximum number of elements for a transpose is 5000 or so, i am able to work with 40,000 no problem - maybe the page you linked is out of date for Excel 2010?

Comment: @TimWilliams i attempted adding the values as a 2D array from the start, but the result was unhelpful - it simply dropped the first value into all slots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually solved this with the  help of a colleague

the problem, as near as i can tell, is that Excel does not like transposing large amounts of data - why this is a problem in Excel, and not any other language, i do not know.

The solution:

```
Range("A2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=(ROW(RC)-2)*" & CStr(dt)
Range("A2").Select
Selection.Copy

'Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(2, max+1)).Select
Columns("A:A").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range("A1").Select
Selection.ClearContents
```

(I wanted to start at A2, leaving space for a header)

`dt` here was the increment, 1e-5

Somehow, this works, and is almost as efficient. It has the downside of pasting to the entire column (it is not possible to paste to a large enough selected range), but that is easier to work around).

Thanks for suggestions guys